# What's the efficient way to upload data using pdf format?

Tags: database, algorithm, data-structures, file-upload, laravel-5.7

A project we working on; every "upload" of customers credit data must have consent form in pdf from customers themselves. So, when I upload credit data, together I should include a consent file. 1 consent file size is a maximum of 1-2mb, containing 8-10 pages. I can be uploading 4K-6K of credit data. I think I can compress the consent files. Is there another way of doing this? I am using PHP Laravel & MySQL. Appreciate any feedback.

Comment: "IS THERE ANOTHER EFFICIENT WAY OF DOING THIS": first of all, using all caps is not a nice way of communicating. But more to the essence: what exactly is "doing this"? Compressing? If you already have a solution and your question is about whether it is efficient, then at least you should provide the relevant code. It might then be even better suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - but you would need to rewrite your question anyway. As it is written now, it is too broad/unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will refine the question.